# Paralel monitor problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, linux-headers

I am using Ubuntu 18.4.1 with one built-in and two external monitors. By normal booting (linux 4.15.0.44-generic) Ubuntu can not loaded. But all things ok when I am using  linux 4.15.0.43-generic at booting.

Comment: I am using HP dock Station with two external monitors. When all of monitors are open all things OK, but when lid closed system crashes. 4.15.0.43-generic was OK and this problem appeared at last header.