# Ubuntu 18.04.1 freezes when connecting to a second screen

Tags: 18.04, display, monitor, bug-reporting, displayport

Everything worked fine until yesterday :) I use a **mini-DP** to connect to my screen for over a year now. Now, when I connect the cable it recognizes it (so I see the Ubuntu background in the screen and can work in my laptop) but **when I close the lid or set the monitor as the main screen** (so as to work only from the monitor screen as I have been doing), **the whole system freezes**. Removing the cable does nothing. Only **hard reboot** (pressing continuously the power button) brings it up.

Kernel: `4.15.0-44-generic`, on `18.04.1 LTS (Bionic)`.

I cannot get anything from `dmesg` because of the freeze, but some errors from `/var/log/syslog` that maybe can help:

```
kernel: [  495.245250] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_GPE.XTBT, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/psparse-550)
...
kernel: [  495.308520] pci 0000:03:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
...
gsd-color[1425]: no xrandr-Dell Inc.-DELL U2417H-5K9YD7AE224L device found: Failed to find output xrandr-Dell Inc.-DELL U2417H-5K9YD7AE224L
...
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1974]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
...
systemd-udevd[4191]: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
...
gnome-shell[1216]: Failed to apply DRM plane transform 0: Permission denied
gnome-shell[1216]: Failed to read EDID from 'eDP-1': No such file or directory
gnome-shell[1216]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed to read EDID from 'eDP-1': No such file or directory]
gsd-color[1425]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file â<80><9c>/home/john/.local/share/icc/edid-18e261c7e650a8a483510701873ac4e2.iccâ<80><9d>: Permission denied
```

Anyone else with the same problem? What do I have to do if this is a general issue to let Ubuntu developers know about it?

Comment: I think you have similar problem with me. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114052/paralel-monitor-problem

Comment: I think is because of a bug in new update package. I am using 4.15.0-43-generic . please look here https://askubuntu.com/a/82144/139749

Comment: It seems like this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1747891) has not been fixed yet.

Comment: Ok, so it seems it is known. Anything I can do to help with the developers' effort? Will they see this message for example?

Comment: Please do consider [Huseyin's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114350/ubuntu-18-04-1-freezes-when-connecting-to-a-second-screen#comment1839893_1114350) as he said he had similar issue and also see [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113743/after-most-recent-kernel-update-4-15-0-44-generic-my-tablet-freezes-whenever-p) too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The issue is of course solved with a previous kernel version :)

Comment: You can solve the problem permanently https://askubuntu.com/a/1115464/139749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is in the `4.15.0-44-generic` kernel and has been solved in the `4.15.0-45-generic`. To manually update, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And that fixes it.