# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes when plugging in usb-c screen

Tags: lenovo, freeze, usb-c

So I have a Lenovo x1 extreme gen2 that I have connected to a dell u3419w screen. This has worked fine for over a year. Since the screen is USB-C I can easily plug in my laptop and automatically my webcam, mouse, keyboard and headset are connected as well. On top of that it charges the laptop, albeit only with 90w instead of 135w.

Now recently since plugging in my laptop the laptop would freeze when I plugged in the USB-C cable to my screen. Unplugging doesn't help it stays frozen and if I'm playing music that stops as well.

When trying out several things the usb-c port stopped altogether and didn't work in Windows either. So Lenovo has replaced the motherboard and it all worked again. However after running an update usb-c stopped working again, even though it now works in windows. When plugging the screen in via hdmi it does work fine. I also tried the 20.04 usb bootable disk and there it freezes as well, even though unplugging usb-c makes the system resume there.

tl;dr, laptop freezes when plugging in usb-c screen. I'm now at a loss how to progress.

Answer (score -1):

From [Ubuntu 18.04.1 freezes when connecting to a second screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114350)

You may wanna try these commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```